# Format of TOC for thesis

Tags: table-of-contents

I apologize for the unspecified and broad question but I have no way to be specific. I'm looking to generate the TOC and List of Figure, List of Table according to the format required by my university.

LIST OF TABLES:

> [image: I need to have a list of tables as shown in the figure.]

TABLE OF CONTENTS:

> [image: and also table of contents.]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the `book` class, this also applies to `extbook`, `scrbook`, etc., you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{Title\hfill Page No.}\par\vspace{-7pt}}
\addtocontents{lot}{\textbf{Table No.\hfill Page No.}\par\vspace{-7pt}}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

and

> [image]